# NSURLResponse - How to get status code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple NSURLRequest:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:myRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // do stuff with response if status is 200
}];
```

How do I get the status code to make sure the request was ok?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you needn't to check the 200 status-code. If your server sends another status-code, you will get an error-object in the completionHandler and can check.

Comment: There are other status codes that represent results that aren't errors, like redirects or not founds, and probably others (auth related, etc) that I can't think of off the top of my head

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Cast an instance of `NSHTTPURLResponse` from the response and use its `statusCode` method.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:myRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
    // do stuff
}];
```

Comment: Can we be sure this is going to indeed be an instance of `NSHTTPURLResponse`, or is it worth checking with `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:`?

Comment: @TimArnold yes, it's an instance of NSHTTPURLResponse, so it has all the properties and methods of that class.

Comment: As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLResponse) say: `Whenever you make an HTTP request, the NSURLResponse object you get back is actually an instance of the NSHTTPURLResponse class.`

Answer (score 33):

In Swift with iOS 9 you can do it this way:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: requestUrl) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 300)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            print("Status code: (\(httpResponse.statusCode))")

            // do stuff.
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Question tagged with objective-c.

Comment: It would be the same methods and order for objective-c.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4**

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    }

})

task.resume()
```